# cannot project entities in Linq 2 NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

I'm working with NHibernate 2 in a .Net project and I'm using the Linq2NHibernate provider.
This simple query

```
var result = from d in session.Linq<Document>()
where d.CreationYear == 2010
select d.ChildEntity).ToList();
```

throws an exception telling me that is impossible to cast ChildEntity type do Document type.
Why is that?
I also tried to translate it in query methods, having

```
session.Linq<Document>()
   .where(d=>d.CreationYear == 2010)
   .select(d=>d.ChildEntity)
   .ToList();
```

Isn't the select method supposed to project an IQueryble into a IQueryble, beeing TResult!=T ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Linq provider is extremely limited and has been unmaintained for several years.

I suggest that you upgrade to the latest stable NHibernate (3.2), which has a much better (and integrated) Linq provider.

Comment: too bad, I'm working on an old project and I cannot change the NHibernate version used.

Comment: You won't be able to use Linq for this query then. Use HQL instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cs
   var result = (from d in session.Linq<Document>()
   where d.CreationYear == 2010
   select new ChildEntityType
     { /* here just do a simple assignments for all ChildEntityType fields
          d.ChildEntity */ } ).ToList();
```

Yes, this could look quite stupid, but linq2nhibernate sometimes behave very strange, when you try to select just an object.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
session.Linq<Document>()
   .Where(d=>d.CreationYear == 2010)
   .Select(d=>d.ChildEntity)
   .ToList<T>();     //where T is typeof(ChildEntity)
```

Comment: shouldn't be able to infer the return type for the select method without explicitly declare it?